# what's the formula of ONVIF #PasswordDigest

Tags: onvif

I'm working on ONVIF of send "GetDeviceInformation". That's required wsse:UsernameToken.
After searching data for authority, there are two faormula:

(1) by "ONVIF-Core-Specification-v241.pdf", "5.12.2.1 Password derivation"

```
PE_UA = base64(HMAC_SHA-1(UA+P_UA,NEP+”ONVIF password”))
```

(2) by soap of WEB protocol

```
Digest = B64ENCODE( SHA1( B64DECODE( Nonce ) + Date + Password ) )
```

I am confused!!which one is correct?

Moreover, when i test ONVIF test tool by wireshark

the XML i got as:

> ```
> <wsse:UsernameToken>
> <wsse:Username>admin</wsse:Username>
> <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordDigest">lu9ywjDwSt8oW7M4tMjCb50/xRg=</wsse:Password>
> <wsse:Nonce>TgBYFHxSc3Oo8yPzwnQn8A==</wsse:Nonce>
> <wsu:Created>2014-06-20T04:41:45Z</wsu:Created>
> </wsse:UsernameToken>
> ```

ok, then I've try to figure out the formula by those data.

a> username: **"admin"**

b> password: **"pass"** ( un-entropy)

c> Nonce: **"TgBYFHxSc3Oo8yPzwnQn8A=="**

d> created: **"2014-06-20T04:41:45Z"**

somehow to get the final password: "**lu9ywjDwSt8oW7M4tMjCb50/xRg=**"

the "nonce" may converted by Base64 so the original should be"4E0058147C527373A8F323F3C27427F0"

I've try use

```
base64(SHA1("TgBYFHxSc3Oo8yPzwnQn8A==2014-06-12T04:03:45Zpass"))
```

or

```
base64(SHA1("4E0058147C527373A8F323F3C27427F0==2014-06-12T04:03:45Zpass"))
```

but I still can't get the password send by Test tool as "lu9ywjDwSt8oW7M4tMjCb50/xRg="

any one could help me to figure out what the exact formula used by ONVIF test tool?

Do need your help!!! thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

finally, the device send OK to me!

After reference to gSoap

At the first, the formula is:

```
Digest = B64ENCODE( SHA1( B64DECODE( Nonce ) + Date + Password ) )
```

for the Nonce, it should be 20 bytes random "numeric" value as:

```
char caNonceTest[20]={0x9E,0xBD,0xBB,0x53,0x7C,0x96,0xB4,0xC1,0xCE,0xEB,
                      0xFB,0x06,0x17,0x31,0x41,0x4E,0x5B,0x68,0x86,0x93};
```

it could be generated by any method (event could be make it)

after getting, **caNonceTest**, like above, the string should be looked like "艋|蹉鋿1AN[h?昍昍昍昍"

and for XML send to device, the base64 should be like "nr27U3yWtMHO6/gGFzFBTltohpPMzMzMzMzMzBQ="

this is the key point of correct foramte! (not ASCII string!)
Moreover, just feed to sha-1 function as the exactly as the **caNonceTest** (no need to convert to Base64)

for the created and password, just feed to sha-1 as string format (ex. "2014-07-08T09:26:13Z" and "pass")

then, world peace!

Comment: Thank you!  This helped me figure out my issue.  Just for other people's benefit in the future, I've put together a gist with example code: https://gist.github.com/lsowen/1a46f9d5fc026e6efc7d